# asp:Menu without CSS and Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

Is there a way to use a asp:Menu Web Control without having it automatically load generated CSS and JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, otherwise it wouldn't even look or act like a menu.

Comment: are there any alternative methods of accomplishing a tab style control without using an asp:Menu? something that controls a asp:MultiView..